# Functional Test Package Naming Conventions?

Tags: naming-conventions, mule

When Functional testing Mule xml configurations, what is the best practice/conventions for naming test packages?

If testing standard Java, usually I use the same package name as the code under test i.e:

**src/main/java
com.mycomapany.MyClass**

**src/test/java
com.mycompany.MyClassTest**

But with mule xml files they are always just in **src/main/app**

i.e **src/main/app/MyMuleFlow.xml**

And tests are in **src/test/java**

So there is no simple correlation. What are the standard conventions for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the code location, you can add: custom source code in **src/main/java** and custom resources in **src/main/resources**.

i.e. Mule projects follow the standard Maven project layout, with the addition of **src/main/app** for Mule configuration files. Therefore you shouldn't feel any difference from your standard Java projects.

As for the package names, there's absolutely no constraint for Mule: do whatever you do in your standard Java projects.

Comment: Ok thanks. But is it possible to put my xml files in src/main/app into specific packages? src/main/app/com.mycompany.util.myutilityflow.xml Will Mule know how to pick them up from there?

Comment: Sure, just use the right paths in `config.resources` inside the deployment descriptor: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Deployment+Descriptor